# focus changes when changing workspaces in gnome 3

Tags: linux, debian, gnome, workspace

When I change between workspaces in GNOME 3 (I use fallback mode) either by using a keyboard shortcut (Ctrl+Alt+arrow_key) or by clicking on the workspace icon in the taskbar, the window with focus is sometimes changed from its previous setting. As an example, I currently have focus on iceweasel (firefox) in Workspace 1. When changing to workspace 2, I set the focus to GNOME terminal. However, when navigating back to Workspace 1, the focus changes to another application (Gimp), and if I change back to Workspace 2, the focus changes to another application in that workspace (LibreOffice). This behavior is rather vexing because each time I change workspaces (Ctrl+Alt+arrow_key), I must additionally change the focused window (Alt+Tab) to restore focus to the window that possessed focus at the moment of departure from that workspace.

Is this a known bug? Or do certain applications greedily assume priority over others (e.g., Gimp over Firefox; LibreOffice over GNOME terminal)? Can this behavior be modified in some configuration file (i.e., can the user mandate that focus not be arbitrarily changed upon changing workspace)?

Comment: I can't offer any solution, just a confirmation that after 3 years it's still like this. The thing that irritates me the most is that focus moves on just pressing `Super`, which means that maximising by using `Super+Up` (the Gnome default combo) maximises the window where the mouse cursor is and not the currently focused window!

Answer (score 0):

Necro-post; sorry ... but a ***decade later*** and *this problem persists*; it plagues me 'til I can't sleep. I finally (accidentally) found a solutions that works for me: the GNOME extension https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4688/focus-follows-workspace/

The extension says that its purpose is to "*Focus the primary monitor after switching workspaces via keyboard*" I've always disregarded this extension bc. I'm using one monitor. However, I installed it and - BAM! - when I flip between workspaces, the last app I was using gets focus instead of the desktop/random app. This is exactly what I wanted!